# How to fit a div's height to wrap around its floated children

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div wrapped around two children, one floated left and the other right. I want to put a border and background around the children, but the div has 0 height since it doesn't resize to fit the children.

Here is an example of it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/VVZ7j/17/

I want the red background to go all the way down. I've tried height:auto, but that didn't work.

Any and all help would be appreciated, thanks.

P.S. I don't want to use any javascript if that's possible.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is a common issue when working with floats. There are several common solutions, which I have ordered by personal preference (best approach first):

1. Use the ::after CSS pseudo element. This is know as the 'clearfix', and works IE8 and up. If you need compatibility with earlier versions of IE, [this answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/74/).

   ```
   .parentelement::after {
       content: "";
       display: table;
       clear: both;
   }
   ```
2. Add the two floats into a container with the CSS attribute `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`. However, this approach can cause issues (e.g. when a tooltip overlaps the edges of the parent element a scrollbar will appear). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/1/).

   ```
   <div style="overflow: auto">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Add a set height to the parent element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/4/).

   ```
   <div style="height: 200px">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Make the parent element a float. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/2/).

   ```
   <div style="float: left">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```
5. Add a div after the floats with `clear: both`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/).

   ```
   <div style="float: left"></div>
   <div style="float: left"></div>
   <div style="clear: both"></div>
   ```

Comment: And do NOT do #1 for adding additional blank, non-semantic elements that just clutter things up.

Comment: I actually tried no.1 and it didn't work (I'm working in WP so I probably put it in slightly the wrong place in the template), but no.2 works a treat, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation.  Every time I have run into this issue I have always used #1 even though it is so ugly but I had not seen a different solution.  I ran into a case where adding an extra div was not an option, did a little extra digging and found your answer.  Now I am armed and dangerous! lol.  Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for providing multiple solutions; each with working fiddles along with a clear explanations.

Comment: +1 for ->  style="overflow: auto" (I am very new to web-development^^)
Thanks! :)

Comment: the best clearfix to wrap children is this method, follow this and wrap floated children

Answer (score 5):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to #wrap. This is a `clear fix`. Here's some documentation about it: http://positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

LE: There are also multiple ways you can achieve this, depending of the browser compatibilty:

1. Add overflow: hidden to the parent container.

`#wrap { overflow: hidden; }`

1. Use a pseudo-element to add `clear: both` .

`#wrap:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table;}`

1. The most commonly used tehnique is to add an extra  as the last element of the parent container.

`<div style="clear:both"></div>`

I preffer `not` to use the 3rd one as you get extra HTML markup.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `overflow: hidden` to your `#wrap` `div`.

Answer (score 2):

I've come to start using this "micro-clearfix" solution from Nicolas Gallagher.

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

```
/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    *zoom:1;
}
```

Just add that to your CSS and any floated element, add the "cf" class to the wrapper of any any element that has floated children.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more div with **style clear:both** before closing a outer div i.e. here "wrap"

--Sample code--

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
        <p>some content at left</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>some content at right</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```